# Convert column headers into index / row values python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following format:

```
Time        07:45:00    08:00:00    08:30:00    08:45:00    09:05:00    09:30:00    10:00:00    11:30:00    Total
2020-03-09  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         400.0       NaN         450.0       NaN     NaN
2020-03-10  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         350.0       NaN         NaN         NaN     10
```

I want to adjust the timestamps into the rows (as indexes or just as values), without the total column, how can I convert it, that it looks like:

```
Time          Timestamp   Value  Total
2020-03-09    07:45:00    NaN    NaN
....
2020-03-09    09:05:00    400.0  NaN
...
20-03-10     11:30:00     NaN    10
```

Comment: Use `df.melt(['Time','Total'], var_name='Timestamp')`

Comment: Perfect, i think thats the basic idea of melt